# For the purposes of complying with an AD, what exactly does "missing and/or incomplete maintenance records" mean?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance, piper-pa-28

I'm considering the purchase of a Piper PA-28R Arrow. I calculated the factored service hours which came up to around 2500 or half of the required FSH to make it subject to the recent [Piper wing spar AD 2020-26-16](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2021/01/15/2021-00044/airworthiness-directives-piper-aircraft-inc-airplanes).  The AD does also require aircraft with "missing or incomplete" logs to comply by performing the inspection outlined in the AD.

The aircraft in question has logs going back to the year of manufacture, however, there is one small gap in the late 70s. A subsequent log entry states previous log lost in hangar fire. The gap is about 6 months in duration, and there were approximately 70 hours accumulated in that time.

Does this small gap in the logbooks make this aircraft subject to the inspection requirements in the AD?  I would think that since only 69 hours were accumulated that it would not, but I'd appreciate any expert opinions on the subject.  Thanks!

Comment: Seems like the only expert opinion that matters is the local FSDO's opinion. Not to mention that, even expert opinions are still _opinions_, which is off-topic for a Stack Exchange site. You should modify your question so that it can be answered _factually_ with citations.

Comment: What does the mechanic doing your pre-buy say?  You are getting a pre-buy inspection done, right?

Comment: Good thought on contacting the FSDO.  I have someone lined up for a pre-buy, but haven't contacted him for details on what he includes yet.  I'll add this to the discussion.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Inspection of logs and AD compliance is normally part of the work your mechanic does on the pre-purchase.   You should ask the mechanic about it now to see if that is any kind of red flag from the get-go that could induce you to walk away, before they get started in the inspection and you have money committed.